# How can I create a trigger for AWS RDS with a AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a problem with my AWS RDS. The instance that I use is Postgres. So, currently, I want to write a lambda function that will validate data for the each record. But, I can not find any solution for to create a trigger when a new record inserted. Could somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess follwoing links would work for you. generally I have never used Lambda trigger on rds.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/capturing-data-changes-in-amazon-aurora-using-aws-lambda/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.CDC.html